# Update the value of specific group field inside repeater field programmatically - Advanced Custom Field (ACF) - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I have group fields inside repeater field. I want to update the value of specific group field value programmatically.

Example - Below is an array of repeater field.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [booking_list] => Array
                (
                    [termin] => November 20, 2021 12:00 am
                    [available_seats] => 5
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [booking_list] => Array
                (
                    [termin] => November 30, 2021 12:00 am
                    [available_seats] => 6
                )

        )

)
```

****I want to update the value of available_seats field**

**Edited -:**
I tried this code but not working.

```
    if( have_rows('booking') ) {
    $i = 0;
    while( have_rows('booking') ) {
        the_row();
        $i++;
        if(have_rows('booking_list')){
            while( have_rows('booking_list') ){
                the_row();
                update_sub_field('available_seats', 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Screenshot**
[Click Me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsjNJ.png)

Comment: See `update_field` helper function provided by ACF and share your try above.

Comment: I have shared the code which I tried. @Saqib Amin

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `update_field` also. You just need to see the `meta-key` in the database. It is usually stored like this: `parent_booking_list_available_seats`. Of course not "parent" you need to have a look in the database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want to update the field in a loop because I have a condition like this if termin = November 30, 2021 12:00 am then update the value of available_seats field of same group

Answer (score 0):

My personal approach is to use `get_field` and since it returns an array, you can just loop through different items and update the fields where necessary.
Below snippet would make all available_seats to 2. You can introduce conditional logic if needed.

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$bookings = get_field( 'booking', $post_id );

foreach ( $bookings as &$booking ) {
    foreach ( $booking['booking_list'] as &$booking_item ) {
        $booking_item['available_seats'] = 2;
    }
}

update_field( 'booking', $booking, $post_id );
```

Comment: can you confirm if 'booking_list' is repeater or group?

Comment: I tried this code but it is not working and I don't know how it also removes all groups excepts first group

Comment: booking_list is a group

Comment: See edited answer above. You should be able to tweak to your needs.

Comment: No its not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you Still need an answer.
This will update a grouped field inside a repeater field.
Repeater > Group > Group Field 1

```
 $repeater = get_field('prepeater_field',$post_id);
   if(count($repeater) > 0){
      $or = 0;
        foreach($repeater as $rfield){
            $ir = 0;
            foreach($rfield as $fields){
              
              $repeater[$or]["group_field_main"]["group_sub_field"] = 'Your new value';
                 
              $ir++;
            }
            $or++;
        }
   
        update_field('prepeater_field',$repeater,$id);
    
   }
```

That's how I made it. Hope this will help you! @kamal